# Boost.Asio linking error

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I'm trying access an extern device via a serial port and want to use Boost.Asio for this propose.
I have build the boost libraries for MinGw and compiled the regex example successful.

But I have problems to compile my code if I include something from Boost.Asio:

```
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>

int main() {

    return 0;
}

g++ -D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\SerialPortTest.o ..\src\SerialPortTest.cpp
g++ -LC:\boost-libs\boost\bin.v2\libs\thread\build\gcc-mingw-4.5.2\release\link-static\threading-multi -LC:\boost-libs\boost\bin.v2\libs\system\build\gcc-mingw-4.5.2\release\link-static\threading-multi -oSerialPortTest.exe src\SerialPortTest.o -lboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_48 -lboost_system-mgw45-mt-1_48
src\SerialPortTest.o: In function `ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7startupERNS2_4dataEhh':
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:39: undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
src\SerialPortTest.o: In function `ZN5boost4asio6detail17winsock_init_base7cleanupERNS2_4dataE':
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:48: undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For me it seems to be a linking problem, but I don't get it.

Comment: you are missing the windows sockets library - reason why this is a comment is that I'm not sure off the top of my head what the library is called under mingw

Comment: And here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033608/mingw-linker-error-winsock

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add -lws2_32 flag to link against WinSockets library.

Also, this might be useful: [MinGW linker error: winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033608/mingw-linker-error-winsock)

Answer (score 0):

You miss wsock32 library. Add this to your dependencies and it should work.