# How to compile memcached on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, memcached, mingw, libevent

I am trying to get `memcached` running on Windows. I have downloaded `memcached` stable latest and compiled it using Mingw under Windows 7. Configure failed with error,

> checking for libevent directory... configure: error: libevent is
>   required.  You can get it from http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/
>
> ```
>   If it's already installed, specify its path using --with-libevent=/dir/
> ```

Then I downloaded `libevent` and compiled it. This produced 3 DLLs, libeventcore, libevent-extra and libevent-2.0.5.

I ran configure on `memcached` again with the option `--with-libevent`. But for some reason, it fails again with the same error. I have no clue on why it is failing. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Or is there a better way to get `memcached` running on Windows? I have seen lot of pre-built binaries for Windows. But all of them uses old versions of `memcached`. And AFAIK, Windows is officially supported by `memcached` in the newer versions.

I am using Windows7 64bit version with MinGW.

Comment: Did you try Couchbase with Memcached Bucket?

Comment: @dasun I haven't tried it. Will give it a shot.

Comment: For compiling you will need not just the .dll which are needed at runtime, but the header files and a .lib. Have you placed those somewhere ?

Comment: @nos : yes. all those are available.

Answer (score 1):

After you run `make` in `libevent` dir you get the files ready, but to make full use of it, they must be installed. So `make install` step is needed. If you configured it with a prefix, it will land in the directory of your choice. Otherwise it is `/usr/local`.

So maybe it's enough to run `make install` in libevent dir and run `configure` from memcache without parameters.

If you still have problems passing the configure stage, look at `config.log`. It shows the source file and the gcc command on which it failed.

Unfortunately successful `configure` is not everything. **Later it fails** on inclusion of `sys/socket.h`, `netinet/in.h` and `netdb.h` and perhaps also `-pthread` gcc parameter. I'm afraid it won't compile on mingw. At least not without a serious porting effort.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Never had an official Memcached port for Windows (Yes, there were few individual efforts. Last knowing porting effort can find on version 1.2.6 [here](http://code.jellycan.com/files/memcached-1.2.6-win32-bin.zip)) Best known Implementation for Memcached for windows on Couchbase with Memcached Bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party I realize but the answer is to use:

```
$ export LIBS=-lws2_32
```

which will place `$LIBS` at the end of compile calls so that it is linked to `libws2_32.a` or winsocks2, but this probably means that your did not configure your build correctly and you will subsequent errors such as `#include <sys/socket.h>` header not found, etc.

see [mingw-linker-error-winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033608/mingw-linker-error-winsock)