# C++ adding static libcurl, wont compile

Tags: c++, libcurl

Im using eclipse and mingw32. My problem is when I add `-static` flag to linker options, i receive this error message:`mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibcurl`

Without `-static` flag, it combines fine and works. I compiled libcurl using mingw32. Then I copied header files to mingw include folder, and files from libcurl lib folder to mingw lib folder. I'm doing something wrong, but I dont know what.

Comment: What is the extension of the libcurl file in the lib folder?

Comment: There are libcurl.res, libcurl.a, libcurl.dll, libcurl,def, and libcurl.rc files in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

-static means "Do not link against shared libraries." 
When you do not use this options linker links the binary with shared version (libcurl.so on linux/libcurl.dll on windows).
Probably you do not have static version of the libcurl on your development enviroment or you do not give the right path of the file (libcurl.lib).

Comment: I have libcurl.a file in lib folder, i think its same thing? And yes, i want make exe work without depencies and that why i use -static.

Comment: you might try to change the extension of that file to lib and try again. As far as I know .lib is used for static libs.

Comment: I tried it, but it gave another:libcurl.lib(easy.o):(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033608/mingw-linker-error-winsock 
you may also need the static version of winsock library or did you link it?